# Rshiny, calling object module in other module

Tags: r, shiny, module, parent

I have a shiny app in which :

- I have a tab called **DATA**. This tab is a module where I call another module to load data. At the same level as this **DATA** module, there is a *dataTableOutput* object
- The module within **DATA** module is called **upload**. It allows to choose the data and then to click on a button to load data.

What I do not succeed to do is, for the moment whatever the data chosen in the filter data, I want to display a table (iris, mtcars, ...) when I click on the button

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

# ======================================================================
# MODULE DATA
# ======================================================================
mod_donnees_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(title = "Data",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               width = 3,
               shiny::tags$h3("Download"),
               
               mod_upload_1_ui(ns("upload_1"))
             ),
             
             mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput(ns("mytable")))
           )
  )
}


mod_donnees_server <- function(id, parent) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    mod_upload_1_server("upload_1", parent)
  })
}




# ======================================================================
# MODULE UPLOAD
# ======================================================================

mod_upload_1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  wellPanel(
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
      inputId = ns("dataset_select"),
      label = "My files : ",
      choices = c("file1", "file2", "file3"),
      multiple = FALSE,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
    ),
    
    
    # Button
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("download_dataset"),
      label = "Download",
      icon = icon("download")
    )
  )
}


mod_upload_1_server <- function(id, parent) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observeEvent(input$download_dataset, {
      output$mytable = renderDT(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
      )
    })
    
  })
}








# ======================================================================
# UI
# ======================================================================    

app_ui <- function(request) {
  navbarPage(
    "Title",
    mod_donnees_ui("data")
  )
}

# ======================================================================
# SERVER
# ======================================================================
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_donnees_server(id = "data", parent = session)
}



shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

# ======================================================================
# MODULE DATA
# ======================================================================
mod_donnees_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(title = "Data",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               # width = 3,
               # shiny::tags$h3("Download")#,
               
               #mod_donnees_ui("data")
             ),
             
             mainPanel(DTOutput(ns("mytable")))
           )
  )
}


mod_donnees_server <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$mytable = renderDT(
      df(), options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  })
}


# ======================================================================
# MODULE UPLOAD
# ======================================================================

mod_upload_1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  wellPanel(
    
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
      inputId = ns("dataset_select"),
      label = "My files : ",
      choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "pressure"),
      multiple = FALSE,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
    ),
    
    # Button
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("download_dataset"),
      label = "Download",
      icon = icon("download")
    )
  )
}


mod_upload_1_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    rv <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    
    observeEvent(input$download_dataset, {
      rv$data <- get(input$dataset_select)
      #print(rv$data[1:9,])
    })
    return(rv)
  })
}
# ======================================================================
# UI
# ======================================================================    

app_ui <- function(request) {
  navbarPage(
    "Title",
    mod_upload_1_ui("upload_1"),
    mod_donnees_ui("data")
  )
}

# ======================================================================
# SERVER
# ======================================================================
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- mod_upload_1_server("upload_1")
  
  mod_donnees_server("data",reactive(df$data))
}

shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)
```